# If I develop websites as a freelancer, can I use my Forge account for all my clients while charging them a monthly rate for services?

Tags: legal, web-development

I've just become a freelance web developer and I have a paid subscription to Forge. I want to host all my new clients' sites on my Forge account. Each client pays an upfront cost for the website, plus a monthly service fee for hosting, updates, analytics, etc.

I'm just not sure if it's allowed by the law and getforge.com. I am in the United States.

Comment: What does Forge's EULA state? Is it part of their acceptable use policy? How about the privacy policies? There are too many variables in order to properly answer this question as-is

Answer (score 0):

Check the terms of service for Forge to see if they say otherwise (I super doubt this), and your development contract, otherwise you're in the clear.

Your clients pay you for services rendered, but you set the prices for that service and can structure it however you want. The charges you pay to make this happen are up to you. You can structure your prices however you like.